# First test case is not getting complete and it proceed for the next one.How can i resolve this?

Tags: java, selenium

I have one test case, in which i have to click on a button to complete my test case but it's response is little slow and my code proceed to the next case prior to the completion of this test case.So My question is how can mark my first test case completed so that next test case run easily.

Can anyone please help and thanks in advance.My code is:

```
    package com.dristhi.automate.testing;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class CreateInteraction {

    WebDriver driver;

    public CreateInteraction(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void testCreateInteraction() {
        if (driver != null) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Open create interaction

            driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestingIdCreateTicketLink")).click();

            List<WebElement> collapsabletab = driver.findElements(By.className("collapsible-header"));

            for (WebElement webElement : collapsabletab) {

                System.out.println(webElement.getText());

                if (webElement.getText().equals("Create Ticket")) {

                    webElement.click();

                    break;

                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // select Email from media drop down

            WebElement media = driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestingIdMediaSelection"));

            WebElement mediaDropdown = media.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gwt-ListBox.browser-default"));
            mediaDropdown.click();

            Select mediaSelect = new Select(mediaDropdown);

            mediaSelect.selectByValue("email");

            // Select queue to create the ticket

            WebElement queue = driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestinfIdQueueSelectionForTicket"));

            WebElement queuedropdown = queue.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gwt-ListBox.browser-default"));

            queuedropdown.click();

            Select queueSelect = new Select(queuedropdown);

            queueSelect.selectByVisibleText("support");

            // Enter To ID value

            WebElement enterToId = driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestingIdForToEmailInCreateTicket"));

            WebElement enterToIdValue = enterToId.findElement(By.tagName("div"));

            enterToIdValue.click();
            WebElement emailToIDInput = enterToIdValue.findElement(By.tagName("input"));

            emailToIDInput.sendKeys("ashwanirao@ameyo.com");

            emailToIDInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

            // Enter subject for the test Email

            WebElement entersubject = driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestingIdForSubjectInCreateTicket"));

            WebElement enterSubjectValue = entersubject.findElement(By.className("gwt-TextBox"));

            enterSubjectValue.sendKeys("First time in the history of drishti to Automate the Manual testing");

            // Click on save button to create the ticket

            driver.findElement(By.id("automationTestingIdSaveTopTicketButton")).click();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `click on a button to complete my test case`? As per _Best Practices_ an action e.g. _clicking a button_ within a _testcase_ must be followed by a **validation**. So shouldn't you validate the result of the click?

Comment: Yes, right I should validate the result of the click.Thanks for your reply